# How solve too many open files error while reading files in hadoop?

Tags: file, hadoop, hdfs

I want to read three different files from three different folders in hdfs so i written a java program to read files from hdfs, but while reading three files i am getting too many open files error.

i want to read a file from folder1 and then check the files in folder2 and matched datas are stored in cassandra so i have written below program

My java program :

```
public class hadoopjoin {


     public  long Dateform(String value) throws Exception
{

  Date dte = null;
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  dte = df.parse(value);
  long ut ;
  ut =dte.getTime();
  return ut;
}


public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{

    Cluster cluster;
    Session session;
    cluster= Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build();

    Metadata metadata=cluster.getMetadata();
    System.out.println("Cluster Connected"+metadata.getClusterName());

    session=cluster.connect();
    hadoop s = new hadoop();


   Configuration conf=new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/bigdata/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/home/bigdata/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
    FileSystem fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
    FileSystem fs1=FileSystem.get(conf);
   FileStatus[] status=fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/bigdata/TAGDETAIL/HADOOPTAGDETAIL"));
          FileStatus[] status1=fs1.listStatus(new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/bigdata/COMMENTUSER/HADOOP")); 
          conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:54310");
          conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:54311");
          conf.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", true);

        session.execute("create table if not exists hadooptagdetailsnew(quesid bigint,accpid bigint,anscount bigint,comcount bigint,viewcount bigint,quescreationdate timestamp,quesyear text,quesmonth text,tags text,quesuserid bigint,quesusername text,quesuserage bigint,queslocation text,quesreputation bigint,quesimage text,anscreationdate timestamp,ansyear text,ansmonth text,ansid bigint,ansuserid bigint,ansname text,ansage bigint,anslocation text,ansreputation bigint,ansimage text,commuserage text,resolution bigint,primary key(quesid,tags,quescreationdate,ansid));");




    for(int i=2;i<status.length;i++)
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
        String line;
        line=br.readLine();
        while(line!=null)
                {
                   if(true)
                   {

                       String[] vals=line.split("\t");
                       long anscreationdate;
                        String ansyear;
                        String ansmonth;
                        long ansid;
                        long ansuserid;
                        String ansusername;
                        String ansimageurl="";
                        long ansuserage;
                        String ansuserlocation;
                        long ansuserreputation;
                        String comuserage="";
                        long comuserpostid;
                        long resolution=0;
                       long quesid=Long.parseLong(vals[0]);
                        long accpid;
                         if( vals[1].isEmpty()||vals[1] == null)
                                {
                                    accpid= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   accpid= Long.parseLong(vals[1]);
                                }
                       long anscount ;
                        if( vals[2].isEmpty()||vals[2] == null)
                                {
                                    anscount= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   anscount= Long.parseLong(vals[2]);
                                }
                       long comcount;
                        if(  vals[3].isEmpty()||vals[3] == null)
                                {
                                    comcount= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   comcount= Long.parseLong(vals[3]);
                                }
                        long viewcount;
                         if(  vals[4].isEmpty()||vals[4] == null)
                                {
                                    viewcount= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   viewcount= Long.parseLong(vals[4]);
                                }


                       long quecreationdate=s.Dateform(vals[5].substring(0, 10));


                     // String quecreationdate = quescreationdate[0];
                         String queyear = vals[6];
                         String quemonth = vals[7];
                           String tags ="hadoop";
                           long queuserid;
                           try{
                               if(vals[9].isEmpty()||vals[9]==null)
                                   queuserid=0;
                               else
                            queuserid = Long.parseLong(vals[9]);

                           }
                           catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                           {
                               queuserid=0;
                           }
                               String queusername;
                               try{
                       if(  vals[10].isEmpty()||vals[10] == null)
                                {
                                    queusername="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   queusername=vals[10];
                                }}
                               catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                               {
                                   queusername="";
                               }
                       long queuserage ;
                       try{
                       if(  vals[11].isEmpty()||vals[11] == null)
                                {
                                    queuserage= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   queuserage= Long.parseLong(vals[11]);
                                }
                       }
                       catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                       {
                           queuserage=0;
                       }
                       String queuserlocation;
                       try{
                       if(  vals[12].isEmpty()||vals[12] == null)
                                {
                                    queuserlocation="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   queuserlocation=vals[12];
                                }
                       }
                       catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                       {
                           queuserlocation="";
                       }
                       long quesuserreputation;
                      try{
                          if(  vals[13].isEmpty()||vals[13] == null)
                                {
                                    quesuserreputation= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   quesuserreputation= Long.parseLong(vals[13]);
                                }
                      }
                      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                      {
                          quesuserreputation=0;
                      }
                      String quesimageurl="";
                      try{
                       if(vals[14].isEmpty()||vals[14] == null)
                                {
                                    quesimageurl=" ";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   quesimageurl=vals[14];
                                }
                      }
                      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                      {
                      quesimageurl=" ";
                      }

                      try{ 
                       if(vals[15].isEmpty()||vals[15] == null)
                                {
                                    anscreationdate= 0;
                                    //System.out.println(anscreationdate);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   anscreationdate= s.Dateform(vals[15].substring(0,10));
                                  // System.out.println(anscreationdate);
                                }
                      }
                      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                      {
                          anscreationdate=0;

                      }
                        if(anscreationdate!=0)
                        {
                         if(  vals[16].isEmpty()||vals[16] == null)
                                {
                                    ansyear="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansyear=vals[16];
                                }

                           if(  vals[17].isEmpty()||vals[17] == null)
                                {
                                    ansmonth="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansmonth=vals[17];
                                }


                        if(  vals[18].isEmpty()||vals[18] == null)
                                {
                                    ansid= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansid= Long.parseLong(vals[18]);
                                }

                        for(int j=2;j<status1.length;j++)
                       {
                         BufferedReader br1=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs1.open(status1[j].getPath())));
                         String line1;
                         line1=br1.readLine();
                         while(line1!=null)
                                 {
                                     if(true)
                                      {
                                     String[] vals1=line1.split("\t");
                                     //System.out.println(vals1[0]+":"+vals1[1]);
                                     long comid=Long.parseLong(vals1[0]);
                                    try{ 
                                     if(comid==ansid||comid==quesid)
                                     {
                                       if(vals1[4]!=null)
                                        comuserage=vals1[4];
                                       comuserage+=",";
                                        // comuserage=vals1[4];
                                     }}
                                    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                                    {
                                        comuserage=null;
                                    }
                                        line1=br1.readLine();

                                      }
                                     else
                                         break;
                                }
                       }
                        if(!(comuserage.isEmpty()))
                       comuserage=comuserage.substring(0, (comuserage.length())-1);
                      // System.out.println(comuserage);
                        try{
                        if(  vals[19].isEmpty()||vals[19] == null)
                                {
                                    ansuserid= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansuserid= Long.parseLong(vals[19]);
                                }
                        }
                        catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                        {
                            ansuserid=0;
                        }
                       try{
                         if(  vals[20].isEmpty()||vals[20] == null)
                                {
                                    ansusername="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansusername=vals[20];
                                }
                       }
                       catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                       {
                           ansusername="";
                       }
                       try{

                        if(  vals[21].isEmpty()||vals[21] == null)
                                {
                                    ansuserage= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansuserage= Long.parseLong(vals[21]);
                                }
                       }
                       catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                       {
                           ansuserage=0;
                       }
                      try{
                         if(  vals[22].isEmpty()||vals[22] == null)
                                {
                                    ansuserlocation="";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansuserlocation=vals[22];
                                }
                      }
                      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                      {
                          ansuserlocation="";
                      }
                      try{ 
                        if(  vals[23].isEmpty()||vals[23] == null)
                                {
                                    ansuserreputation= 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansuserreputation= Long.parseLong(vals[23]);
                                }
                      }
                      catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                      {
                          ansuserreputation=0;
                      }
                     try{                        

                       if(vals[24].isEmpty()||vals[24] == null)
                                {
                                    ansimageurl=" ";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   ansimageurl=vals[24];
                                }
                     }
                     catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                     {
                         ansimageurl="";
                     }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ansyear="";
                      ansmonth="";
                        ansid=0;
                        ansuserid=0;
                      ansusername="";
                        ansimageurl="";
                      ansuserage=0;
                       ansuserlocation="";
                      ansuserreputation=0;
                        }


                      String[] cols={"quesid","accpid","anscount","comcount","viewcount","quescreationdate","quesyear","quesmonth","tags","quesuserid","quesusername","quesuserage","queslocation","quesreputation","quesimage","anscreationdate","ansyear","ansmonth","ansid","ansuserid","ansname","ansage","anslocation","ansreputation","ansimage","commuserage","resolution"};

                      Object[] value={quesid,accpid,
                       anscount, 
                       comcount,
                       viewcount,
                       quecreationdate,
                       queyear,
                          quemonth,
                           tags,
                       queuserid,
                       queusername,
                       queuserage,
                       queuserlocation ,
                       quesuserreputation,
                      quesimageurl,
                       anscreationdate,
                      ansyear, 
                       ansmonth,
                       ansid,
                       ansuserid,
                       ansusername,
                       ansuserage, 
                       ansuserlocation,
                       ansuserreputation,
                       ansimageurl,
                       comuserage,
                       resolution
                      };        

                        Statement ins=QueryBuilder.insertInto("stackexchange","hadooptagdetailsnew").values(cols,value);
                        System.out.println(ins+","+comuserage);
                     session.execute(ins);

line =br.readLine();
                   }
                   else{
                       break;
                   }                           
                   }
    }

 cluster.shutdown();   
 }

}
```

Error :

```
14/05/15 09:14:11 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:50010, add to deadNodes and continuejava.net.SocketException: Too many open files
14/05/15 09:14:11 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DFS Read: java.io.IOException: Could not obtain block: blk_-8822436491089176071_6549 file=/user/bigdata/COMMENTUSER/HADOOP/part-m-00000
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.chooseDataNode(DFSClient.java:2460)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSClient.java:2252)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.read(DFSClient.java:2415)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
```

help to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you please check whether your datanode is up and available at port 50010?

Comment: Seems unlikely, but it's worth checking out the `ulimit` on your system to see whether the number of open files are being limited by the Unix/Linux system. `ulimit -a` will give you the details.

Comment: Closing the stream's that you opened should help more than increasing the ulimit.

Comment: Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Name: 127.0.0.1:50010
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 68862722048 (64.13 GB)
DFS Used: 2187116544 (2.04 GB)
Non DFS Used: 17575038976 (16.37 GB)
DFS Remaining: 49100566528(45.73 GB)
DFS Used%: 3.18%
DFS Remaining%: 71.3%
Last contact: Thu May 15 16:03:37 IST 2014